# 繰り返し処理で配列のインデックスと要素を連結したい

Tags: java

javaのStringBufferでする処理について質問があります。
最終的な表示の仕方としては、

１「ネ」２「ウシ」３「トラ」４「ウ」５「タツ」６「ミ」７「ウマ」８「ヒツジ」９「サル」
１０「トリ」１１「イヌ」１２「イ」

と連続した表示をさせたいと思っています。
appendとfor文を使用してやっていたのですが、うまくいきません。
※干支は配列に入れています。

どなたかappendを使用しうまく表示させる方法が
お分かりの方がいらっしゃいましたら、
ヒントだけでも教えていただけないでしょうか。
宜しくお願いします。

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] eto = {"ネ", "ウシ", "トラ", "ウ", "タツ", "ミ", "ウマ", "ヒツジ", "サル", "トリ", "イヌ", "イ"};

    StringBuffer strbufr = new StringBuffer();

    for (int z = 1; z <= 12; z++) {
        sb.append(z);

    }

    System.out.println(strbufr);

}
```

Comment: 関連する質問（[コメント参照](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35442/%E7%B9%B0%E3%82%8A%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%A7%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A8%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%A0%E3%82%92%E9%80%A3%E7%B5%90%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84#comment35251_35443)）： https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/35450/19110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

どううまくいかないのかわかりませんが、こんな感じでいかがでしょう?

```
    for (int z = 1; z <= 12; z++) {
        strbufr.append(z);
        strbufr.append("「");
        strbufr.append(eto[z - 1]);
        strbufr.append("」");
    }
```

Comment: 直接質問とは関係無いですが、`for (int z = 1; z <= 12; z++)`より`for (int z = 1; z <= eto.length; z++)`の方が配列の長さが変わった時などに対応できるので一般的にはいいかと。干支の数が変わることは無いと思いますが。。。

Comment: そうですね。その辺りは質問者さんに合わせました。

Comment: 丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます。勉強になりました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: あとすみません。もし、上記の処理の数字を２４に引き伸ばし、干支を２回繰り返し表示させるとすると、appendとfor文だけでは難しいでしょうか。ご回答いただいたものを参考にして、switch文を使うとできたのですが、使わずに簡易的にできないかと思いましてお聞きしてみました。表示としては１「ネ」２「ウシ」３「トラ」４「ウ」５「タツ」６「ミ」７「ウマ」８「ヒツジ」９「サル」
１０「トリ」１１「イヌ」１２「イ」１３「ネ」１４「ウシ」１５「トラ」１６「ウ」１７「タツ」１８「ミ」１９「ウマ」２０「ヒツジ」２１「サル」
２２「トリ」２３「イヌ」２４「イ」といった感じなのですが。。お手隙の時で結構ですので、もしお分かりでしたら教えていただけないでしょうか。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: @guest 難しくは無いですが、このサイトでは原則1つの質問では1つのことのみ聞くことになっていて、[コメントでズルズル質問を増やして問題になった](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2463/%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e8%80%85%e3%81%a8%e5%9b%9e%e7%ad%94%e8%80%85%e3%81%a7%e3%82%84%e3%82%8a%e5%8f%96%e3%82%8a%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%a9%e3%82%93%e3%81%a9%e3%82%93%e5%86%85%e5%ae%b9%e3%81%8c%e9%95%b7%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f%e6%8a%95%e7%a8%bf%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e5%af%be%e5%bf%9c%e3%81%99%e3%82%8c%e3%81%b0%e8%89%af%e3%81%84)ことがあったので、別に質問を作ったほうがいいと思います。注目もされますし。

Comment: かしこまりました。ご指摘ありがとうございます！